# Delete lines which have more number of specific word

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a large file which looks like:

```
India 07 1800 BAHRAICH 42273 +28.4 +26.7 NA 997.1 1 NA NA
India 07 1800 BAHRAICH 42273 +28.4 +26.7 NA 997.1 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BALASORE 42895 +29.0 +26.8 NA 999.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BANGALORE 43295 +23.0 +17.4 908.1 geopotential_of_850mb_=_492 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BANGALORE 43295 +23.0 +17.4 908.1 geopotential_of_850mb_=_492 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BAREILLY 42189 +28.4 +26.2 NA 997.4 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BAREILLY 42189 +28.4 +26.2 NA 997.4 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BARMER 42435 +35.6 +22.6 NA 997.6 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHOPAL_BAIRAGHAR 42667 +23.6 +23.3 942.7 1000.5 13 NA NA
India 07 1800 BHOPAL_BAIRAGHAR 42667 +23.6 +23.3 942.7 1000.5 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUBANESHWAR 42971 +28.0 +25.7 NA 1000.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUJ-RUDRAMATA 42634 +29.6 +25.7 NA 999.5 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BIKANER 42165 +33.8 +25.1 NA 994.0 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BIKANER 42165 +33.8 +25.1 NA 994.0 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BOMBAY_SANTACRUZ 43003 +29.0 +26.8 NA 1004.4 10 NA NA
India 07 1800 BOMBAY_SANTACRUZ 43003 +29.0 +26.8 NA 1004.4 NA NA NA
```

In this file 2-3 lines are same with only one entry are different in the form of entry "NA" which can occur at any position. I want keep the line with less number of "NA".

I am not able to think a solution for this.

I want output as:

```
India 07 1800 BAHRAICH 42273 +28.4 +26.7 NA 997.1 1 NA NA
India 07 1800 BALASORE 42895 +29.0 +26.8 NA 999.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BANGALORE 43295 +23.0 +17.4 908.1 geopotential_of_850mb_=_492 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BAREILLY 42189 +28.4 +26.2 NA 997.4 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BARMER 42435 +35.6 +22.6 NA 997.6 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHOPAL_BAIRAGHAR 42667 +23.6 +23.3 942.7 1000.5 13 NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUBANESHWAR 42971 +28.0 +25.7 NA 1000.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUJ-RUDRAMATA 42634 +29.6 +25.7 NA 999.5 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BIKANER 42165 +33.8 +25.1 NA 994.0 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BOMBAY_SANTACRUZ 43003 +29.0 +26.8 NA 1004.4 10 NA NA
```

I will appreciate even logic to do so.

Thanks

Comment: The most common field is the 5th column but 1st , 2nd, 3rd are also the same. I want to keep line with least number of NA. But i realized that the difference between number of NAs should not be more then one between two sorted consecutive lines. only then my purpose can be achieved. Max 4 lines can be same based on 1,2,3,5 column so i will execute the desired command 4 times. But for now i have to find the solution in case of at least 2 same consecutive lines. let me edit my input file. Thanks

Comment: Edited. 
let me again write in a simple way.
i have a file in which 2 lines are same on the basis of 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 5th column.
Between these two lines one difference is number of NAs in other columns. lets say one line have 4 NAs in others column and second line have 5 NAs then i want to delete line having 5 NAs and keep lin with 4 NAs. In the same way for other same line i want to keep line with less number of NAs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the *key* is the 4th field and records with identical keys are consecutive (and I understood your question correctly), you could do something like:

```
perl -lane '
  $na = grep {$_ eq "NA"} @F;

  if ($F[3] eq $last_key) {
    if ($na < $min_na) {
      $min_na = $na; $min = $_
    }
  } else {
    print $min unless $. == 1;
    $last_key = $F[3]; $min = $_; $min_na = $na;
  }
  END{print $min if $.}' < your-file
```

Which among consecutive lines with same 4th field, prints the first one with the least number of `NA` fields.

If they're not consecutive, you could use some sorting:

```
< yourfile awk '{for (i=n=0;i<NF;i++) if ($i == "NA") n++; print n, $0}' |
  sort -k5,5 -k1,1n |
  sort -muk5,5 |
  cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

With `busybox` `sort`, you'd want to add the `-s` option to the second invocation as it seems to do some level of sorting of the input again despite the `-m`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Now i can edit as per my whole requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
perl -pae '
   last if eof;
   my($M, $N) = ("@F[0..4]", $,.<>);
   print,$_=$N,@F=split,redo if substr($N,0,length($M)) ne $M;
   $_ = ($_, $N)[s/NA/NA/g > $N =~ s//NA/g];
' file
```

.

```
sed -Ee '
   $!N
   /^((\S+\s+){5}).*\n\1/!{P;D;}
   h;s/.*/ & /
   :a;s/ NA (.*\n.*) NA / \1 /;ta
   /\n.* NA /bb
   g;s/.*\n//;b
   :b;g;s/\n.*//
' file
```

**Results**

```
India 07 1800 BAHRAICH 42273 +28.4 +26.7 NA 997.1 1 NA NA
India 07 1800 BALASORE 42895 +29.0 +26.8 NA 999.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BANGALORE 43295 +23.0 +17.4 908.1 geopotential_of_850mb_=_492 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BAREILLY 42189 +28.4 +26.2 NA 997.4 Trace NA NA
India 07 1800 BARMER 42435 +35.6 +22.6 NA 997.6 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHOPAL_BAIRAGHAR 42667 +23.6 +23.3 942.7 1000.5 13 NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUBANESHWAR 42971 +28.0 +25.7 NA 1000.7 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BHUJ-RUDRAMATA 42634 +29.6 +25.7 NA 999.5 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BIKANER 42165 +33.8 +25.1 NA 994.0 NA NA NA
India 07 1800 BOMBAY_SANTACRUZ 43003 +29.0 +26.8 NA 1004.4 10 NA NA
```